# vtk IntersectWithLine() function using a normal as the line

Tags: c++, vtk

I have two isosurfaces (skull and skin). given point A on skull isosurface, i calculated the normal at point A using "double *pos = pickerCell->GetPickNormal()". 
when i print pos, this is what i got: -6.2367, 1.98263, -0.9823
could someone explain to me what these 3 values mean?

I would like to find the intersection point of this normal of point A with the skin isosurface.

Could I use IntersectWithLine() function to do so? If yes, the line in my case would then be the normal? what is the start and end point of the normal?

Or is there a better way of doing ?

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, you need to define the line to intersect with as two points. What is commonly done is to start at the point, P, that you picked (the same point where the normal, v, was computed) and compute two points, A = P + v delta and B = P - v delta where you have to set delta using context (if your model is in a unit cube, delta might be something like .01, where if your model has units of size 1000, delta may be 1, etc.).

Also, I'm not sure why the normal the cell picker returns is not normalized, but I'm assuming that if you normalize it it is the surface normal. I'd call it something other than 'pos' to avoid confusion (as it is a direction, not a position).